# Collect UserName/User-ID in Google Analytics Using HTTP Authentication

Tags: google-analytics

We maintain a site that uses http authentication to identify registered users, rather than a cookie, and allow them access to a secure portion of our site.  Is there a way to track the user data (username and where they go) within Google Analytics once they login to our site?  We can't seem to figure this out...

Thanks!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because its not programming related may be better suited for https://webapps.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

The information for http auth is passed via the [Authorization header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Authorization) which you can access in a serverside language of your choice. That will give you a username.

AFAIK there is no way to retrieve http headers in a clientside language during the initial page request.

Also keep in mind that storing personally identifiable data in Google Analytics violates the terms of service.

As to "where they go", if you want to look at individual users their way through your site can be followed in the User Explorer Report. All other reports give you aggregated data only.